# Kendo UI grid hide columns with zero values

Tags: c#, kendo-ui

I would like to hide those columns (that contain integer values) in my Kendo Grid in which all cells contain '0' values. Is the solution for that easy?

Comment: Did you try to bind columns dynamically? i.e If you know that one column is full of 0, then you don't bind it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can hide a column via the [hideColumn](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#hidecolumn) method. You can get the data to which the grid is bound to using the [data](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#data) method of the data source. Then traverse it to find if all records contain zeros. Here is a quick example:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var data = grid.dataSource.data();

var allZeroes = true;

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // say the name of the field to which the column is bound is "foo"
    if (data[i].foo != 0) { 
       allZeroes = false;

       break;
    }
}

if (allZeroes) {
   grid.hideColumn("foo");
}
```

Comment: well, I need to check if the user entered more than 10 digit in a column field, I'm trying this:  data[i].foo.length > 10, but its not working. can you please let me know whats going wrong? @atanas

Comment: @Jain consider opening a new question.